# Finding phone hash device id for admob

Tags: android, hash, unity-game-engine, admob

I have integrated AdMob ads into my Unity game using the google admob plugin and I need to find my phone's hash id to test the ads. Anyone know how to do this within Unity? Again, I have developed in Unity and NOT Eclipse. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found this and it worked...

[AdMob device id finder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pe.go_com.admobdeviceidfinder&hl=en)

Again, using LogCat was not an option in my case.